# Django count pks excluding relations

Tags: python, django

On a Django project I have People model which has a few relations (one of them - foreign key - is in the example). I want to sort a result of how many people were added each day, using this:

```
truncated_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day', 'created_at')
people = People.objects.extra({'day': truncated_date})
report = people.values('day').annotate(total=Count('pk')).order_by('-day')
```

The problem is, it also counts all pks from relations. How could I exclude them, and count only pks of People model?

Models:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Observation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    people = models.ForeignKey(
        'people.People', related_name='observations'
    )
```

And some other relations, but as you see, they all have very similar fields, like name, description, created_at, creator. I also cannot add any additional fields.

Comment: Can you show us your model definition?

Comment: Sure, added to the original post.

Comment: Doing a count on one of the other fields works?

Comment: `Count(field)` will count all rows where `field` is not null, so you could try counting on your `name` field instead. also... I don't see any many-to-many relations here

Comment: Sorry, it's not complete model structure, there are many-to-many and foreign keys, etc., and name, description, created_at and creator are on every model, so I can't really count any other field. I was hoping I can exclude fields from other models somehow. FYI, I can't also add any additional field, as this is not my project, I'm just making an extension using those models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:
users = User.objects.all()
count_by_day = [{'count':users.filter(date_joined__day=x.day).count(),
               'date':x} for x in User.objects.dates('date_joined','days')]

Comment: Thanks. All I needed to change, is dates -> date times.